# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: While loading pickle file

Tags: python, pickle, oserror

I am trying to do the following:

1. Fetch content from the file './lists/Topic_list.pkl'
2. Write a new line to the existing data.
3. Export it to the same file.

It is getting this error after working for many iterations:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: './lists/Topic_list.pkl'

Please consider the following:

- The file exists.
- That part of the code is called iteratively.
- It worked perfectly till it got this error.

Screenshot attached below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed.

This is what I did:

- In case the error is found:
- Wait for one second.
- Re-Try.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg3AA.png)